# C function not printing result

Tags: c

I have this assignment, the task is to recieve a string, invert the order of all chars and convert them to their "opposite", eg. A->Z, b->y, 0->9 . "Cat" would become "gzX". All arrays should be dynamic.

My code compiles without errors or warning, but unfortunately it doesn't print anything.

The Main is completely predefined and I am not allowed to change it at all.

If my error cannot be deduced from the following, shortened code I wil gladly provide the full function.
Also Im sure this code is terrible, any other tips are appreciated.

Main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *twisted(const char * const str);
int main(int carg, const char **varg){
    if (carg != 2) return -1;
    char * twstr = twisted(varg[1]);
    printf("die verwürfelte Version von \"%s\" ist \"%s\".\n", varg[1], twstr);
    free (twstr);
    return 0;
}
```

my Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char *twisted (const char *const str)
{
  char *untwisted;
  size_t length = strlen (untwisted);
  untwisted = (char *) calloc (length, sizeof (char));
  scanf ("%99s", untwisted);
  char *reverse (){
```

[...] //reversing the chars in untwisted

```
free(untwisted);
untwisted = NULL;
}

char *twist (char *str)
  {


char *twister = (char *) malloc (sizeof (char) + strlen (str) + 1);
char *reversed = (char *) malloc (sizeof (char) + strlen (str) + 1);
reversed = reverse ();
```

[...]//"twisting" the chars

```
free(twister);
twister = NULL;
free(reversed);
reversed = NULL;


}
```

Comment: Do you have `reverse` defined as a nested function? That's not standard C. And there are also other things in the shown code that's odd or suspect, like calling `strlen` in the *uninitialized* pointer `untwisted`. Please try to create a proper [mre] to show us.

Comment: "My code compiles without errors or warning" - that's because you don't enable any warnings. Try `-Wall`.

Comment: @Siguza Thank you, now I can solve the issue on my own! Just noticed Im also supposed to compile with -Werror